# Exposé App Focus Loss issue

Tags: macos, mission-control, expose

macOS Sierra (10.12.6)

When I enter Exposé using any method, I select my desired window and it comes to the forefront, but then focus switches back to my previous app no matter what.

**Example:**

1. Doing something in Safari
2. Use Exposé to switch to Email (not app switcher)
3. Email comes to the front (or un-minimizes)
4. Safari comes back to the front

This also happens if I switch between windows of the same app. Meaning, if I switch from one email window to another email window via Expose, Safari again takes focus.

It's a simple bug with Exposé not giving focus to the correct app, but this all works perfectly on my other computer running Yosemite.

Comment: What if you try safe mode? If it works in osx's safe mode, that could mean that a third party app is affecting it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that occurs when the app in question is assigned to "All Desktops".

Here's a work-around: right click the App in the dock and select `Options > Assign to > This Desktop` or `None`.

[image: screenshot]